# How can I pivot this tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Considering this tibble

```
library(tibble)
mytab <- tribble(
  ~siren_ent, ~nbeta_dep01, ~nbeta_dep02, ~effeta_dep01, ~effeta_dep02, ~categ, 
  "A",   3,   0,   50,   0,   "X",
  "B",   0,   2,    0,  30,   "X",
  "C",   1,   1,  10,   15,   "Y"
)
```

I would like to pivot it to get this result...

```
> result
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  DEP   categ nbeta effeta
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 01    X         3     50
2 01    X         1     10
3 02    Y         2     30
4 02    Y         1     15
```

If you have a solution with tidyverse, I'm interested.

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: There are two columns called `effeta_dep01`, I assume one should be `effeta_dep02`?

Comment: yes sorry, I edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the second of your `effeta_dep01` columns should, in fact, be called `effeta_dep02`. If so, then this gives something close to the desired output:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

mytab %>%
  pivot_longer(nbeta_dep01:effeta_dep02,
               names_sep = "_dep",
               names_to = c(".value", "dep")) %>% 
  filter(nbeta > 0) %>% 
  select(-siren_ent)
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  categ dep   nbeta effeta
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 X     01        3     50
2 X     02        2     30
3 Y     01        1     10
4 Y     02        1     15
```

I assume your expected output is incorrect, but if not, I'd be happy to know what transform you expect.

Answer (score 1):

There is a duplicate column name in your example data and also several zeroes that do not appear in the final result. By combining two pivots and a group_by we can reach the desired result:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

mytab %>% select(-siren_ent) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-categ) %>% 
  separate(name, '_', into = c('name','dep')) %>% 
  mutate(dep = parse_number(dep)) %>% 
  group_by(categ, dep, name) %>% 
  summarise(value = max(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = 'name', values_from = 'value')

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   categ, dep [4]
  categ   dep effeta nbeta
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 X         1     50     3
2 X         2     30     2
3 Y         1     10     1
4 Y         2     15     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this also:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
new <- mytab %>% pivot_longer(-c(siren_ent,categ)) %>%
  separate(name,sep='_',c('var','index')) %>%
  select(-index) %>%
  group_by(siren_ent,categ,var) %>%
  mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var,values_from=value) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-id) %>%
  filter(nbeta>0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  siren_ent categ nbeta effeta
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         X         3     50
2 B         X         2     30
3 C         Y         1     10
4 C         Y         1     15
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(mytab)[, siren_ent := NULL], 
   id.var = 'categ', measure = patterns("^nbeta", "^effeta"), 
   value.name = c('nbeta', 'effeta'), variable.name = 'dep')[nbeta != 0]
#   categ dep nbeta effeta
#1:     X   1     3     50
#2:     Y   1     1     10
#3:     X   2     2     30
#4:     Y   2     1     15
```